# Tuleap LDAP authentication and binding with current user login credentials

Tags: active-directory, ldap, tuleap

Can I set up the tuleap LDAP plugin to bind to the server with the current login credentials the user has inputted? This is how the Jenkins plugin functions but is is unclear if I can set up the tuleap plugin the same way.

Also, is there a way to see any logs from the LDAP plugin to try to figure out what ldap commands it is sending?

Answer (score 1):

Tuleap does support LDAP auth for both OpenLDAP and Active Directory. Once you install the plugin, you will be asked the type of directory you are using.

More information in the doc: http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/administration-guide/services.html#ldap

Comment: The doc doesn't give the information I need. Is there a way of binding to the server without defining a bind_dn or bind_password in the ldap.inc? For example, when I try to log in to tuleap can it use those details to bind to the ldap server?

Comment: Yes, just don't define those variables (comment it out in ldap.inc) and Tuleap will do a anonymous bind to your LDAP server

Comment: I do not want anonymous(this isn't enabled on my server), I want it to authenticate with the login details

Comment: If your servere doesn't have anonymous access then you must have a kind of "generic user" to make the initial search (this is mandatory to find the right dn to use for authentication challenge). Therefore you will have to fill bind_dn bind_password with this "generic user" access.

Comment: Can I choose not to use a generic user and use the login details?

Comment: Nop, Tuleap muse have a user to perform the first search to get the dn corresponding to the user that want to authenticate.

Comment: I don't see why it NEEDS a 'generic user' and cannot do this with the login details.

Comment: As said, the code need to do a lookup with the submitted login to get the user dn and then use this dn + submitted password to do the user authentication. It might be possible to do differently if we can predict the DN from the user login but anyway, this is the way the code is working right now

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :). Can we just use the DN from the sys_ldap_dn setting?

Comment: I don't understand the question